# It's possible to show different content on notebook lcd an vga output connector?

Tags: laptop, video, multiple-monitors, playback

I want to do a program that on notebook LCD show a controller of what we see on VGA output connector, it is possible to do that?

For instance, on LCD you can see a remote control (play, stop, volume) an on VGA you see the film without controls.

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: I think I'll be using c# on windows platform

Comment: Which Windows? XP? Vista?

Comment: I suppose it needs saying that the notebook has to support dual monitors (hardware) and has to be running in dual monitor mode. The hardware seems pretty standard in business-class notebooks of recent vintage.

Answer (score 0):

Generally (in windows) go into your display properties and if you have a monitor plugges into the VGA port, you should be able to see two screens.

In modern OS's, when you plug in an external VGA device, it should prompt you for what to do with it.

Comment: Ok, so, I think I have to make 2 windows forms, one positioned on (x,y) (0,0) and the other positioned on (1024,0) on 1024x768 screen  resolution and setting up an extended windows for 2 monitors. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Setup multiple monitors via Windows (or whatever OS you're using); the { video card / video card driver / OS } may not support it though. I don't think there's a standard 'programming' answer though, i.e. I'm sure you *could* program the (suitably capable) video card directly, but that's probably silly.